# Accuracy of my SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I am mostly posting this to have my logic checked. The query is running fine, but I was hoping to get a more experienced set of eyes to make sure I structured this properly.

The intent of this query is to find all duplicate `PaperPersonID` values, and associate them with the client's `DisplayName` and the `UserName` of the staff responsible for creating the duplicate object.

This query returns `99 rows`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        AO.DisplayName AS AODisplayName,
        AD.UserName AS ADUserName,
        GP.PaperPersonID,
        AD.OperationType

  FROM <Redacted>.[AuditedObjectWeakReference] AO

  INNER JOIN <Redacted>.GenericPerson GP
  ON GP.Oid = AO.GuidId

  INNER JOIN <Redacted>.AuditDataItemPersistent AD
  ON AO.Oid = AD.AuditedObject

  WHERE PaperPersonID IS NOT NULL
  AND AD.OperationType = 'ObjectCreated'
  AND PaperPersonID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT PaperPersonID
        FROM GenericPerson

        WHERE PaperPersonID IS NOT NULL

        GROUP BY PaperPersonID
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1)


  GROUP BY AO.DisplayName, AD.UserName, GP.PaperPersonID, AD.OperationType
  ORDER BY PaperPersonID, UserName, DisplayName
```

Again, this seems to be working okay, but I don't really have a baseline to compare this to, so I don't know what the expected result is. I have run a query against only the ID field, and that returns `53 rows`.

```
USE <Redacted>

SELECT PaperPersonID
FROM GenericPerson

WHERE PaperPersonID IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY PaperPersonID
HAVING COUNT(PaperPersonID) >1
```

However, the first query shows me each duplicate entry, whereas the second query shows each duplicate entry once, so I think I'm in the ballpark with `99 rows`

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I just realized I have a superfluous `SELECT DISTINCT` in my second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good method for duplicate checking is using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and perhaps the `COUNT()` function with `OVER()`:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PaperPersonID ORDER BY PaperPersonID) AS RN
                       ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PaperPersonID) AS Dup_CT
              FROM <Redacted>.[AuditedObjectWeakReference])
 SELECT *
 FROM cte
 WHERE Dup_CT > 1
```

This will not filter records like `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` does in your second query, and numbers the duplicates.   If you put this in a cte you can then filter by using `WHERE RN = 1`.  This is also typically more efficient than using your `PaperPersonID IN ()`.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY PaperPersonID`  then for each unique PaperPersonID value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Aggregate functions such as `COUNT()` and `SUM()` can also use `OVER()`, with the `PARTITION BY` functioning the same way and `ORDER BY` not being required.

Comment: That returned `2559` results. Did you mean to run this independently, or incorporate it into my statement?

Comment: Oh, I suppose I should filter for `WHERE Dup_CT > 1` ... genius

Comment: @NonSecwitter Indeed, I had just updated the answer with that too, sometimes it's helpful to see all records, other times just the duplicates without losing full row details.

Comment: Got it. This is way advanced. I just got acquainted with IN and UNPIVOT ... So, I think I'll use this, but I need to come back and break it down. I appreciate your input!

Comment: I can accept answers in two minutes. Whats with the `;` at the beginning of that query?

Comment: The semicolon is because the code here is using a common table expression (cte). A cte requires that the previous statement be terminated with a semicolon. As a result many people developed the habit of "starting" a cte with a semicolon.

Comment: Added my standard blurb about `ROW_NUMBER()` to the answer.  A semicolon is a statement terminator, they should be used before a `cte` when the `cte` is not the first statement in a batch, so I'm in the habit of always using them before a `cte`.